# signalR passing objects to hub

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub

I need to be able to somehow associate `List<string>` (that gets loaded in my controller) with a `connectionId` that is generated in the HUB.

In my MVC app I have an Action that fills `List<string>` with some data. After the page is loaded, OnConnected method is executed in my Hub where a new `ConnectionId` is generated. I would like to associate that `ConnectionId`with my`List<string>`.

Since OnConnected is executed after the action completes I don't believe there's another way of doing it. Is there?

How would I pass a List (or some other object) to my hub so that is associated with a specific ConnectionId?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing data to your hub, take in data from your hub.

So for instance you can use static dictionaries/lists to have the two reference eachother:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public override OnConnected()
    {
        MyController.Associate(Context.ConnectionId);
    }
}

public class MyController
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>> cidToList = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>();
    public static List<string> mylist = new List<string>();

    public static void Associate(string cid)
    {
        cidToList.TryAdd(cid, mylist);
    }
}
```

Comment: that works. I assume the last connectionId will be assigned to LAST List<string> object